# Compare data from one worksheet to another workbook without opening it

Tags: excel, vba, filecompare

Can anyone help me out with this VBA Macros query? I want to compare a worksheet with another worksheet in a different workbook. However, I don't want to open that workbook when comparing. I just want to changes to be shown in the current worksheet that I am using.

Is there something like a temporary data storage using Macros which stores the data temporarily from another workbook, compares it without ever physically opening the workbook?

Comment: What did you try? If you show your effort, more people will be willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this.  **You can use regular worksheets formulas, even if the other file isn't open.**

For example, if we want to compare cell `A1` of the current worksheet to cell `A1` on worksheet `Sheet1` of an (open or closed) Excel workbook saved as `c:\myPath\myFile.xlsm`, we could use:

```
=IF(A1='C:\myPath\[myFile.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1,"It's a Match!","Not a Match")
```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : **[Create an external reference (link) to a cell range in another workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f)**
- Microsoft Press : **[How to Combine Data from Multiple Sources in Microsoft Excel 2016](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2447199&seqNum=2)** (book excerpt)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That helped me with some new information. @ashleedawg However, I don't think I phrased my question correctly. I want the command to compare information and if any information is different, I want it to only output that information stating that's different (or output it in different color).